# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at com.auth.net.commons.authorize.net.GetSettledBatchList.main in Auth.net Java SDK

Tags: java, authorize.net

I need help from `Authorized.net Java SDK` experts. I am `GetSettledBatchList` transaction with the following code, but it gives me exceptions, I am not able to understand which Date format it accepts.

The error comes for reference:

```
11/05/15 00:32:56,875:  INFO [pool-1-thread-1] (net.authorize.util.LogHelper:24) - Use Proxy: 'false'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.auth.net.commons.authorize.net.GetSettledBatchList.main(GetSettledBatchList.java:52)
```

The code which I developed so far for reference:  Please help me how to solve this error.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;

import net.authorize.Environment;
import net.authorize.api.contract.v1.GetSettledBatchListRequest;
import net.authorize.api.contract.v1.GetSettledBatchListResponse;
import net.authorize.api.contract.v1.MerchantAuthenticationType;
import net.authorize.api.contract.v1.MessageTypeEnum;
import net.authorize.api.controller.GetSettledBatchListController;
import net.authorize.api.controller.base.ApiOperationBase;

public class GetSettledBatchList {
    public static final String apiLoginId= "XXXXX";
    public static final String transactionKey= "XXXX";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, DatatypeConfigurationException {
        GregorianCalendar gc=new GregorianCalendar();
        ApiOperationBase.setEnvironment(Environment.SANDBOX);

        MerchantAuthenticationType merchantAuthenticationType= new MerchantAuthenticationType() ;
        merchantAuthenticationType.setName(apiLoginId);
        merchantAuthenticationType.setTransactionKey(transactionKey);
        ApiOperationBase.setMerchantAuthentication(merchantAuthenticationType);

        GetSettledBatchListRequest getRequest = new GetSettledBatchListRequest();

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        Date firstSettlementDate = df.parse("2015-01-26");
        gc.setTime(firstSettlementDate);

        Date lastSettlementDate = df.parse("2015-05-05");
        gc.setTime(lastSettlementDate);

        getRequest.setFirstSettlementDate(DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc));
        getRequest.setLastSettlementDate(DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc));
        getRequest.setMerchantAuthentication(merchantAuthenticationType);
        GetSettledBatchListController controller = new GetSettledBatchListController(getRequest);
        controller.execute();

        GetSettledBatchListResponse getResponse = new GetSettledBatchListResponse();
        if (getResponse!=null) {

            if (getResponse.getMessages().getResultCode() == MessageTypeEnum.OK) {
                System.out.println(getResponse.getMessages().getMessage().get(0).getCode());
                System.out.println(getResponse.getMessages().getMessage().get(0).getText());
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Failed to get settled batch list:  " + getResponse.getMessages().getResultCode());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something on line 52 is null. Try adding null checks:

```
if (getResponse!=null && getResponse.getMessages() != null && getResponse.getMessages().getResultCode() != null) {

        if (getResponse.getMessages().getResultCode() == MessageTypeEnum.OK) {
            if (getResponse.getMessages().getMessage() != null && getResponse.getMessages().getMessage().get(0) != null) {
                System.out.println(getResponse.getMessages().getMessage().get(0).getCode());
                System.out.println(getResponse.getMessages().getMessage().get(0).getText());
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Failed to get settled batch list:  " + getResponse.getMessages().getResultCode());
        }
}
```

Comment: In sandbox account I can see the list of settled transactions, but through Java Auth API how we can see that, as something do to with dates only

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Attach a debugger to your code and step through each line to find the source of the error.

Comment: davehenry - Please see the link https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-java/issues/61#issuecomment-157100238, this is the issue which I was facing.

Answer (score 0):

Line 47 does not make sense in your code. The line

```
GetSettledBatchListResponse getResponse = new GetSettledBatchListResponse();
```

returns an empty response from the API. You do not have any line to actually extract the response from the controller.

If you look at this [link](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-java/blob/master/src/main/java/net/authorize/sample/TransactionReporting/GetSettledBatchList.java) in the Authorize.Net GitHub repository for the sample codes, you will notice that the above line should be replaced by

```
GetSettledBatchListResponse getResponse = controller.getApiResponse();
```

Try this and get back to us with the result.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in latest version version of `anet-java-sdk` `1.8.6` per link **https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-java/issues/61**. So below code works fine. Make sure when you're using dates, `FirstSettlementDate` and `LastSettlementDate` gap should not be more that 30 days.

```
public class SettledTransactionDetails {
    public static final String apiLoginID= "XXXXX";
    public static final String transactionKey= "XXXXXX";

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        Merchant merchant = Merchant.createMerchant(Environment.SANDBOX, apiLoginID, transactionKey);

        // get the list of Unsettled transactions 
        net.authorize.reporting.Transaction transaction =
                merchant.createReportingTransaction(TransactionType.GET_SETTLED_BATCH_LIST);

        ReportingDetails reportingDetails = ReportingDetails.createReportingDetails();

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        reportingDetails.setBatchFirstSettlementDate(formatter.parse("16/06/2015"));
        reportingDetails.setBatchLastSettlementDate(formatter.parse("15/07/2015"));
        reportingDetails.setBatchIncludeStatistics(true);
        transaction.setReportingDetails(reportingDetails);

        Result<Transaction> result =(Result<Transaction>) merchant.postTransaction(transaction);
        System.out.println("Result : " + result.getResultCode());

        ArrayList<BatchDetails> batchDetailsList = result.getReportingDetails().getBatchDetailsList();
        for (int i = 0; i < batchDetailsList.size(); i++) {
            ArrayList<BatchStatistics> batchStatisticsList = batchDetailsList.get(i).getBatchStatisticsList();
            for (int j = 0; j < batchStatisticsList.size(); j++) {
                BatchStatistics batchStatistics = batchStatisticsList.get(j);
                System.out.println("====================== "  + j+ " start");
                System.out.println("Account Type : [" + batchStatistics.getAccountType()+"]");
                System.out.println("Charge Amount : [" + batchStatistics.getChargeAmount()+"]");
                System.out.println("Charge BackAmount : [" + batchStatistics.getChargebackAmount()+"]");
                System.out.println("Charge Charge Back Amount : [" + batchStatistics.getChargeChargebackAmount()+"]");
                System.out.println("Charge Returned Items Amount [: " + batchStatistics.getChargeReturnedItemsAmount()+"]");
                System.out.println("Refund Amount : [" + batchStatistics.getRefundAmount());
                System.out.println("Refund Charge Back Amount : [" + batchStatistics.getRefundChargebackAmount());
                System.out.println("Account Type : [" + batchStatistics.getAccountType());
                System.out.println("====================== "  + j+ " end");
            }
        }

    }
}
```